# Wikipedia API for nan latin scripts

Tags: json, wikipedia-api, non-latin

I am using wikipedia api to get json from a specific title and parsing it in my webpage. I want to add language translator like wiki does but all the non latin scripts like greek,chinese,japanese,hebrew etc are not working.It is perfectly working for other languages like french,german etc.

I am adding abbreviations for language like en for english,el for greek etc to the front of link wikipedia.org/wiki and adding search title at the end of the link.

for ex: if user provides albert einstein as title and greek as language,then the link would be http://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/albert%20einstein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the page title for Albert Einstein in Greek is [Άλμπερτ Αϊνστάιν](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%86%CE%BB%CE%BC%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%81%CF%84_%CE%91%CF%8A%CE%BD%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%B9%CE%BD).

If you know the right title in English, you might consider finding the English page, and then use interwiki links ([`prop=iwlinks`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Iwlinks) in the API) to find the title in Greek, or any other language.